# Unable to scrape data from bootstrap datatables using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to **scrape** data from each `<td>` of table but getting data which is on current page of pagination using `javascript`

```
   function export_to_excel()
    {
        var table = $("table tbody");
        var count=0;
        var object;
        var array_push=[];
        table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
              count=count + 1;
               object = {
                Account_Code: $tds.eq(0).text(),
                Account_Name: $tds.eq(1).text(),
                Opening_Balance: $tds.eq(2).text(),
                Status: $tds.eq(3).text(),
                Debit: $tds.eq(4).text(),
                Credit: $tds.eq(5).text(),
                Closing_Balance: $tds.eq(6).text(),
                c_Status: $tds.eq(7).text(),
            }

           if($(this).children().attr("class") !="displaynone") {
               array_push.push(object)
           }
        });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url()?>TrialBalanceReport",
                data:  {"data":array_push},
                success: function(msg)
                {

                }
            });

    }
```

above given function getting data getting of td which is displaying on current page of pagination all other pages data is not there when i am printing `$_POST` on server side script **TrialBalanceReport.php** i am using bootstrap datatables

Comment: Did you mean 'scrape'?

Comment: If you look at the HTML/DOM, then you'll only see what is currently shown (ie the current page).  You need to look at the underlying data.  It's not clear what "bootstrap datatables" is, but if you mean js datatables then use `.data`.  https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()

Comment: Try to console.log(object); to see it is already set or not if yes call your function on document ready if you didn't do this,